# Amazon S3 : How to allow access to a specific path, only for a specific referer?

Tags: amazon-s3, policy

I have a Amazon S3 bucket `mybucket` and only want to enable access to content in a specific nested folder (or in S3 terms, with a specific "prefix").

I tried the following S3 bucket policy but it doesn't work. After adding the condition I started getting access denied errors in the browser.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy for mybucket",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow access to public content only from my.domain.com",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/public/content/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://my.domain.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What should the policy look like to achieve this?

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  This policy looks valid.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot, I clarified my statement. To be honest, I'm still debugging this. I seem to receive the referer, at least at Cloudfront which distributes the content in my bucket (Logs on S3 where not available yet). The behaviour is really weird, when I add the condition with the referer I get access denied errors.

Comment: CloudFront doesn't forward the referer to S3 by default, and it's a little bit tricky to get it to do so -- and, that's probably a bad idea anyway since it will hurt your cache hit ratio (CloudFront would check the cache for a response for the same URL *and* referer so each possible referer would have its own cached copy, otherwise the request would be sent to S3 to validate the referer).  Use a CloudFront origin access identity to allow CloudFront to access the bucket, and the use [AWS Web Application Firewall](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) to control access to CloudFront.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the policy in to two statements. One to allow access to the folder (prefix), and one to deny access when the referer is not one of the white listed domains:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy for mybucket",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow access to public content",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/public/content/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Deny access to public content when not on my.domain.com",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/public/content/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://my.domain.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That worked for me. I was already using Cloudfront and had the bucket restricted so I didn't need the second part of the policy.

Comment: Hmmm... I think I spoke too soon.  I ended up adding a separate behaviour on my Cloudfront distribution to make this work.